# JavaScript createElement appendChild how to avoid duplicated

Tags: javascript

I'm using JavaScript to code a function that once the submit button has been clicked ,the function will read JSON , and dynamically create html base on the JSON.

The issue is ,if I click the submit button twice ,duplicated table rows will be created, if there a way to avoid the duplicated rows ,no matter how many times I hit the submit button ?

Html:

```
   <div id='container'>
    <button id="Submit" onclick="submit();">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
   const obj = {
                "Hard Violation": [
                   {
                        "Violation": 0,
                        "Initial": "BSI",
                        "Total Confirmed": 9,
                    },
                    {
                        "Violation": 6,
                        "Initial": "ASI",
                        "Total Confirmed": 3,
                    }
                ]
            };
        
    function submit(){
 
    const Violation=obj['Hard Violation']
    
    // create table header
    const thead = document.createElement("thead");
    const headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
    Object.keys(hardViolationSummary[0]).forEach(key => {
      const th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerText = key;
      headerRow1.appendChild(th);
    });
    thead.appendChild(headerRow);
    table.appendChild(thead);
    
   // create table body
      const tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
      Violation.forEach(obj => {
      const row = document.createElement("tr");
      Object.values(obj).forEach(value => {
      const td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerText = value;
      row.appendChild(td);
          });
          tbody.appendChild(row);
        });
        table.appendChild(tbody);
    
    // append table to violationsTable div
       container.appendChild(table);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first check if there's already a table with the id `violationTable` in the HTML container. If such a table exists, then remove it using the `remove()` method of the DOM element. Create a new table and add it to the HTML container.

```
function submit() {
  const Violation = obj['Hard Violation'];
  const existingTable = document.getElementById('violationTable');

  if (existingTable) {
    //if a table already exists, remove it before creating a new one
    existingTable.remove();
  }
  .....
  .....
```

**Another Solution:**

You can use a flag variable `tableCreated` that is initially set to `false`. When the function is first called, it checks whether `tableCreated` is false and only creates a new table if it is `false`. After the table is created, `tableCreated` is set to true, which prevents a new table from being created on subsequent button clicks.

```
let tableCreated = false;

function submit() {
  const Violation = obj['Hard Violation'];

  if (!tableCreated) {
    //create table
    const table = document.createElement('table');
    ...
    ...
    ...
    //set the flag to true
    tableCreated = true;
  }
}
```